# How to merge two rows with same column value into one row

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, codeigniter-4

I'm trying to fetch data using Codeigniter 4 and query builder. I have a table structure like below

| id | employee_id | in_out | time |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EMP_001 | in | 08:10 |
| 2 | EMP_001 | out | 10:30 |
| 3 | EMP_002 | in | 09:15 |

I want to retrieve data and output to the view as single array, combining two rows of records into one like below

| id | employee_id | in | out |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | EMP_001 | 08:10 | 10:30 |
| 2 | EMP_002 | 09:15 |  |

my current model is below

```
    $builder = $this->db->table('attendance');
    $builder->select('id, employee_id, in_out, time');
    $builder->select('id, employee_id, in_out, CONCAT(DATE_FORMAT(time, "%r"), '.', DATE_FORMAT(time, "%r")) AS clock_time', FALSE);
    $builder->groupBy('employee_id');
    $query = $builder->get()->getResult();

    return $query;
```

I'm trying to figure out using `CONCAT` or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can resolve this by joining (left join) your table `attendance` with itself.

The columns `in` and `out` are aliases from the column `time`. The first SELECTgets you all `in` values by each employee, which by your example has always a value.

Now we only need to add the `out` part, which is done via a LEFT JOIN, querying the table `attendance` again.

this is the raw MySQL query, which you can see working in [this sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5348940/5)

```
SELECT
    `t1`.`id`,
    `t1`.`employee_id`,
    `t1`.`time` AS `in`,
    `t2`.`time` AS `out`
FROM
    `attendance` `t1`
LEFT JOIN(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        `attendance`
    WHERE
        `in_out` = 'out'
) t2
ON
    `t1`.`employee_id` = `t2`.`employee_id`
WHERE
    `t1`.`in_out` = 'in'
```

this can be "translated" into a CI query using the CI Query Builder Class. Note the use of table aliases `t1` and `t2` as well as the column aliases `in` and `out`

```
$builder = $this->db->table('attendance t1');
$builder->select('t1.id, t1.employee_id, t1.time as in, t2.time as out');
$builder->join('(SELECT * FROM attendance WHERE in_out = "out") t2', 't1.employee_id = t2.employee_id', 'left')
$builder->where(t1.in_out, 'in');
$query = $builder->get()->getResult();

return $query;
```

while this is to answer your question *How to merge two rows with same column value into one row* you will need to prepare for several time attendance issues, like

- multiple check-in/out from same employee at same day
- check out after midnight (next day)
- employee forgot to check in earlier and wants to check out
- employee forgot to check out earlier and wants to check in

and probably others

Comment: Tq. Solved. I'm already take noted of your point of concern. For multiple check-in/out at same day, i'm controlled checking via controller to allowing only one in one out. Point (2): i'm already captured DATETIME. But for point (3 & 4), i will try to figure out. TQ for solution :-)

Comment: great I could help, anyway: point 1) is a big problem IMO; employees check out for lunch and come back, employees have some family issues to deal with (go to doctor with kids) and come back, might have their own medical reasons to leave and come back.